# Can I use a SQL Server project to create/manage a LocalDB file?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, localdb

I'm new to SQLServer and related Visual Studio tools though I know SQL well.

I want to have a local test DB on my dev PC with some stored procedures (so it needs to be SQL Server not SQLLite). LocalDB seems the answer and I can create a LocalDB MDF file through Server Explorer. But I don't think I can/should be putting an MDF file in version control - other developers need to have this DB for *their* local testing too.

I feel like the Visual Studio SQL Server Project type is what I'm after here but I don't see how such a project is linked to an actual DB. In my mind I imagine setting up a SQLServer project in VS, adding tables/stored procs/etc, and this will automatically build a LocalDB MDF file.

I'm unsure how thee things hang together and where the files all go, can someone help clarify this?

I'm basically starting from the point: I have a SLN with my C# projects in. My C# code calls certain stored procedures using a connections string from configuration but no DB actually exists in the wild yet. Any developer ideally needs a dummy DB to be created when they build the code, not have to create it manually, without installing SQLServer.
So it seems like I want to create a SQLServer Project in my solution, which will magically create a LocalDB. Is that feasible/correct?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use Visual Studio at all, would SSMS not meet the requirements if you only want to execute some stored procedures? SQL Server Express is free, it's just limited on size, I believe that the SQL developers edition is free as of pretty recently, may be worth looking into.

I've got a couple of installations of SQL Server on Hyper-V Virtual machines too for testing purposes, this could be an option.

Comment: I'm doing my coding (C#) in VS so it just seemed like this would be neater, if everything could be done in software I'm already using (and understand). It's really only a tiny, 'dummy' DB so running up a VM just seems like overkill.